# Simplifying Array declaration in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Consider following array declarations,

```
int[] num2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int[] num3 = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num2));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num3));
```

> So for the `num3` if I passed directly the right hand side declaration to a functions its valid.
>
> i.e. `Arrays.toString(new int[]{1,2,3})` But Why can't the `num2` approach

if I call `someFunction({1,2,3,4,4})` it throws an Error as

> **illegal start of an expression.**

### If both declarations are valid then why can't I use it in arguments of method ?

I was trying to simply the approach , when passing some temporary array to a function such as

`somefunction(new int[]{1,2,3,4})`

Is it possible simplify this in java ? any java 8 tricks  ?

Comment: did you make typos in println method you called both num2 check once

Comment: somefunction(new int[]{1,2,3,4}) you can do that what is the problem

Comment: I want to use it as `somefunc({1,2,3,4})`

Comment: Boring answer: because the JLS defines it that way: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create an instance to pass it to the method, for example :

```
someFunction(new int[]{});
```

It doesn't work in your case, because you passe only the type `int[]` and this is not correct.

> Is it possible simplify this in java ? any java 8 tricks ?
>
> I want to use it as `somefunc({1,2,3,4})`

Then you can use varargs, like so :

```
ReturnType someFunction(int... a){}
```

then you call this method like so:

```
someFunction(1, 2, 3, 4); // valid 
someFunction(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4}); // valid
someFunction(num2); // valid
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not get what is a purpose, but consider this code to pass any int array to some fucntion:

```
somefucntion(Stream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1).limit(5).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray());

void somefucntion(int[] ints) {
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Number[] longs1 = new Long[] { 1L, 2L, 3L };
Number[] longs2 = new Long[] { 4L, 5L, 6L };
Number[] concatted = arrayConcat(longs1, longs2);
```

Comment: I want to simplify this `somefunction(new int[]{1,2,3,4})` not valid array declarations